# Why is Corey Beaulieu's guest solo out of key?

Tags: metal

In Annihilator's album 'Metal', in the track called '[Kicked](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u04f6XCOLEc)' there are 2 guest solos by Trivium's Corey Beaulieu. While the first solo seems fine, the second solo (3:35 - 3:55) seems out of key. I don't think that this was deliberate so what is the story behind this? Did he recieve a different backing track at first or something like that? Does anybody know?

Comment: It doesn't seem out of key to me.

Comment: There are definitely some odd tones in the solo, though not necessarily out of tune. Perhaps just a little bit... wierd?

Comment: @Magnilex We are not used to Corey playing 'a little bit wierd' solos. That's why I think something might me going on.

Comment: Annihilator just released a renewed, partially re-recorded version of the album, but this particular solo and the backing track don't seem to be changed.

Comment: @user1079505 Yes I saw that. Still seems a bit strange to me but I have to accept that this is what Corey wanted (shrugs)